# Outlook automatic archive on network drive

Tags: vba, email, outlook, autosave

Am I able to use Outlook to automatically link a folder in outlook with a folder on the network drive?

Let's say I want to use VBA to modify a folder called `"New York Store"` within outlook. I would like to modify the folder, so whenever I put an email into this folder, it will save the email on a destination on the computer such as `"X:\Stores\Outlook Archive\New York Store"`, and when it has done so, it permanent delete the email from Outlook?

Is it possible to modify a folder (by VBA or something else) to save the email(s) within a folder, and when it has done so, delete the emails from Outlook permanently?

Please let me know, if this is possible :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: ***Yes***.  It is possible.  You'll need to brush up on programmatic folder control and find a way to "watch" the folder for new items.

Is there a reason that there has to be a folder involved?  You'd save a few steps with something like a custom button on the Mail Item ribbon to save to file and delete message.

Or, considerably fewer keystrokes:

> <kbd>F12</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>

It will work on one or more items, no additional folder required, and after the first time you save an item at your location `X:\Stores\Outlook Archive\New York Store` it will default to that folder.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.

Secondly, the reason why I would make a folder, is that we would have a lot of different stores.
Let's say that I would have 6 stores. Making 6 different custom buttons might end up being confusing, and if I hit the wrong one, I won't be able to recognize which documents that belongs to which store.

But the command "F12" is definitely something I would take to consideration :)

Comment: You're welcome! Okay, so the requirement to implement this in several stores changes the context of your question significantly.

Comment: oh - a set of folders in YOUR Outlook to distribute email messages to individual stores (and then to delete the emails from your end after saving to the shared folder) ...there must be something I'm missing? Also, which version of Outlook?  Now I'm **really curious**. Could  you explain further; walk me through step by step?  (1) You get an email message from somewhere. (2) You need to save this email message in a certain folder (3) you want to be able to drag the email to an Outlook folder...... help me help you, with more info please  :)

Comment: At the moment, some changes in the law in our country determines that the daily work routine has to change. At the moment we already have several folders for each store, where we save our mails, if they should be needed in the future.

The law has changed, and now we have to save such things on the computer, so hacking attacks shouldn't easily get access to these information easily through Outlook.

I will continue using the example such as New York Store and Washington Store etc.
Lets say the owner of the New York Store sends me some personally sensitive information about a customer.

Comment: To continue the above:

It could either be personally sensitive information about a customer or an employee.
At this moment I would put this into New York Store, since it has relation to this store. And now I will be able to find the email quickly in the future, if needed.

The function should be able to recognize that when I drag emails into a folder, it should save the email as an Outlook item on the network drive. And afterwards this shouldn't be available within Outlook, other than when I open the saved version, it will show the email with the attachments it might have :)

Comment: And I'm using Outlook 365 (2016)... I think I forgot to mention that :)

Comment: oh I'm beginning to understand what you're trying to do.  You need these messages and any attached files,off of your computer, placed into a network drive for long-term storage, not only for the sake of delivery to the stores, but also so you can **continue** to have access to them in the future via the folder...  correct?  Is your Outlook currently setup to store your "Personal Folders" PST file locally or on an Exchange Server?

Comment: There are many existing solutions available for encrypting email folders, including built into Access (such as encryption if you're on an Exchange Server).  Also, if a hacker were able to get into your computer, they would easily be able to get into network drives as well.  Another concern is that, since this now has legal undertones, you (or I, or most others) are not recognized as experts in network security and thus probably should not be building our own tools for ensuring security (especially in VBA).

Comment: ...What if the hacker accessed your computer and changed your VBA without you realizing, to send himself second copies of everything item you file?  Outlook has features for shared folders, and others for mail security.  Do you think you'll be able to do a better job than Microsoft did?  No offense, and I'm not saying it's impossible to code, but I've learned that too often, existing solutions are ignored and the "hard way" (and in this case the "more vulnerable way") is overlooked by those thinking they are the only one who's ever needed a solution to a problem like theirs.

Comment: [How to encrypt a PST file](https://itstillworks.com/encrypt-pst-file-11358.html)  ...[How to encrypt mail on an exchange server](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-tips-for-helping-users-keep-outlook-data-secure/) and other mail security tips. . . .[How to grant Exchange and Outlook mailbox permissions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2572646/how-to-grant-exchange-and-outlook-mailbox-permissions-in-office-365-de) . . . . [Encrypt in Outlook 365](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Encrypt-email-messages-373339cb-bf1a-4509-b296-802a39d801dc)